# Eevee render times weirdness

Tags: rendering

I wonder if anyone might shed some light. I bought a new PC for speedier work than my old imac under advice from a friend. My imac used to render a particular Blender file and scene  in Eevee - 43 seconds and Cycles 7 min, 51 secs. My friends PC did the same scene in Eevee 19 secs and Cycles - 29 secs. I recieved my new PC and was very happy to find it did the same file and scene in 22 secs and Cycles 11 seconds. However, after about 2 weeks with the PC we are working on a new file and scene in Blender. Render times for this on my friend's PC is Eevee - 1 min 17 secs and Cycles - 2 mins 14. On My PC it is taking Eevee - 2 mins 36 secs and Cycles - 2 mins 31 secs (eevee taking longer than cycles?). Can anyone explain to me what's going on to cause such relatively slow comparisons to my friends render speeds on this new file when the others were close or better on the other file. Also, why eevee seems to be as slow as cycles too on this new file? Also, in the System/Preferences/Cycles Render device options, in CUDA it is showing both NVIDIA and INTEL options and also the same in Optix. Should I be chosing one, the other, or both in these settings? Many thanks in advance. Ps: i tested it the other day and the render in Eevee weirdly took 43 seconds. I've since re treied but it's always back to 2 minutes plus. I've updated Nvidia drives too.

Comment: Might it be related to how much graphics memory you have? If your GPU runs low on available memory, it could be "paging" some if it to your system RAM. Look in your task manager under the GPU performance graph, and see if "Shared GPU memory"  value goes up a lot when you render.